# Formula reference holds for n cells in a row, then switches to new reference

Tags: excel, reference, formula

I wonder if there's a quick solution to the following:

My goal is to divide a cell value by three, using the same value for three cells in a row, then switch to the next value in the series for another three cells in a row, and so on.

So my starting data would look like:

```
  A   B   C   D   E 
1 9   12  6  21   27
2 30   9  3   0   3
3 ...
```

I want the new cells to look like:

```
  AA   AB   AC   AD   AE ...
1 3    3    3    4    4 
2 10   10   10   3    3
...
```

Where the cell AA1 = A1/3, AB1 = A1/3, AC1 = A1/3, but AD1 = B1/3 and so on.

I need to do this for many observations, preferably using an excel formula.

Does anyone have any ideas on quick solutions?

Really appreciate your help.

Best,
Henry

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(1:1,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN(A1)/3,0))/3
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this does not work for me - and I believe it's my error. I assumed I could use the same formula if the original data is located on the right of the computed data. (Opposite of the example I posted.) Is a similar solution available? Here is an example of this formula applied: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-1FNRLPWgCX20WRkjJDDU_qSx_pMVNGCSNa9jfu9dY/edit?usp=sharing                                Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @hraw45 If the data is to the right of the formula, the full row reference should not be used. Instead, specify the exact data range i.e. instead of ```1:1``` use for example ```$O1:$X1```

Comment: p.s your file is not accessible.

Comment: I fixed access to my file. I am very close; however, I get 1) the wrong value for my first observation (it seems to be referencing the last column in my data range; and 2) I am unable to drag the formula across to different cells. I receive an "out of range" for INDEX's parameter 3, value 6. Thanks again for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @hraw45 Why did you change the ```COLUMN(A1)``` function to ```COLUMN(O1)```? I said only the full row reference should be changed. Use the formula: ```=INDEX($O1:$S1,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN(A1)/3,0))/3```